# Apply a plugin to jQuery at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, bootstrap-select

I have installed jQuery and a jQuery-Plugin via npm and want to use it inside a ES6 module. The problem is, that the plugin documentation only knows about a global installation via the script tag, which I don't want to use in my system.

How can I apply the plugin to jQuery, so I can use it inside my class?

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import selectpicker from 'bootstrap-select';

// Maybe something like "$.register(selectpicker);"?

const element = document.createElement('select');
$(element).selectpicker(); // Undefined method "selectpicker"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to import bootstrap-select directly: `import 'bootstrap-select;`.